# extracting domain names from a file in bash using regular expression

Tags: regex, bash

I'm using bash to extract domain names from file:

```
cat file | tr ' ' '\n' |egrep -q '[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})'
```

it returns nothing, what's wrong?
I expect to extract things like test.com, hello.net etc.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of 'file'?

Comment: IF there are truly commas, you may want to add a | sed 's/ ,/ /g' prior to your tr...

Comment: Without looking at your sample input it is difficult to understand the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `egrep -q`, where `-q` means "Quiet;   do   not  write  anything  to  standard  output."

So you're not seeing any output because you have explicitly asked for no output.

Comment: now it seems to return things like a@a.com, instead of just a.com, is there a way to return just the matched patterns?

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of your input data so that we have something we can test ourselves.

Comment: By default, `egrep` outputs the entire matching line.  You are probably looking for something like `grep -oP '(?<=@)[-A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[-A-Za-z0-9]+)+(?= |$)' file` ... assuming you have GNU `grep` or similar.

Comment: I might just pipe through `cut` or similar, but since we still don't have any sample input we're just guessing...